# How to disable leading space from hyperref?

Tags: hyperref, spacing, macros

I defined the following command:

```
\newcommand{\reqWVSDataSource}[0]{
\hyperref[req:wvsDataSource]{\textit{Req01}}}
```

If I use it like this:

```
(\reqWVSDataSource)
```

hyperref adds a leading space. Thus the result is "( Req01)" instead of "(Req01)".

How can I disable this leading space?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try the following (note the "%" at the end of the first line):

```
\newcommand{\reqWVSDataSource}[0]{%
\hyperref[req:wvsDataSource]{\textit{Req01}}}
```

EDIT: For an explanation see [this](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-spinmacro) entry in the TeX FAQ.

EDIT2: As your new command takes no argument, the optional count argument `[0]` in the definition may be omitted.